# React Context value doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I just finished working on a custom Context Provider and I came across a problem. The context isn't getting updated with the data from the function inside of it. It just stays the same (as specified default value).

I'm not really sure what the bug is :/

Here's the code:

`useBreakpoints.tsx`

```
// Functions
import { createContext } from 'react';

// Hooks
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// Types
import type { ReactNode } from 'react';

type Width = number | undefined;

interface Breakpoints {
  [key: number | string]: number;
}

interface Values {
  [key: number | string]: boolean;
}

interface IProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  breakpoints: Breakpoints;
}

// Context
export const BreakpointsContext = createContext({});

export const BreakpointsProvider = ({ children, breakpoints }: IProps) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState<Width>(undefined);
  const [values, setValues] = useState<Values | undefined>(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const handleResize = () => {
        setWidth(window.innerWidth);
      };

      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

      handleResize();

      return () =>
        window.removeEventListener('resize', () => {
          handleResize();
        });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (width !== undefined) {
      const handleValues = () => {
        Object.keys(breakpoints).forEach((breakpoint, index) => {
          setValues((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            [breakpoint]: width >= Object.values(breakpoints)[index],
          }));
        });
      };

      handleValues();

      return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleValues);
    }
  }, [width]);

  const exposed = {
    width,
    values,
  };

  return <BreakpointsContext.Provider value={exposed}>{children}</BreakpointsContext.Provider>;
};

export const useBreakpoints = () => useContext(BreakpointsContext);

export default BreakpointsProvider;
```

`_app.tsx`

```
// Providers
import { ThemeProvider } from 'next-themes';
import BreakpointsProvider from '../hooks/useBreakpoints';

// Variables
import { Style } from '@master/css';

// Styles
import '@master/normal.css';
import '../styles/master.css';

// Types
import { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react';
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';

export type NextPageWithLayout<P = {}, IP = P> = NextPage<P, IP> & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode;
};

interface AppPropsWithLayout extends AppProps {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout;
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page);

  return getLayout(
    <ThemeProvider themes={Style.colorSchemes} attribute="class">
      <BreakpointsProvider breakpoints={Style.breakpoints}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </BreakpointsProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Then I call it inside of a component like this

```
const test = useBreakpoints();
console.log(test);
```

I am working with NextJS, if that changes anything.

Comment: Side note: this `window.removeEventListener('resize', () => {
          handleResize();
        });` doesn't do anything. You are creating a new function here so it will not be removed

Comment: It should be `window.removeEventListener('resize, handleResize);`

Comment: Previously that file was structured differently, so it was a leftover from that.

Comment: Are you sure that `Style.breakpoints` is defined?

Comment: What is the shape of `breakpoints`? Cause this line ```[breakpoint]: width >= Object.values(breakpoints)[index],``` doesn't make any sense, and also the entire `useEffect` block with it

Comment: Yes it is, but not on first re-render. Actually, if I ``console.log(exposed)`` I get something like this):
- {width: undefined, value: undefined}
- {width: x, value: undefined}
- {width: x: value: x}

Comment: @Joshua the point of that is for me to get truthy or false values of all breakpoints (if it matches, basically). The initial object looks just like it's specified in a type: ``{name:value, ...}``, then it returns ``{name: boolean, ...}``. Again, the functionality here works as expected, it's just the value itself that is not being passed to context.